# Show where $f(x,y) = \sqrt{|x| + |y|}$ is differentiable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Classify where $f(x,y) = \sqrt{|x| + |y|}$ is differentiable -- where it's not, prove it, and where it is, prove it.

My thoughts: 
For $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$, we can just treat it as $f(a,b) = \sqrt{a+b}$ (where $a = |x|, x\neq 0$ and $b=|y|, y\neq 0$). Then $Df(a,b) = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{a+b}} & \frac{1}{2\sqrt{a+b}} \end{bmatrix}$. Since those are both continuous on the domains I defined, then $f(x,y)$ is differentiable for $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$.

Two problems -- 
1) I don't know if the above is rigorous enough. What would be the 'next step' of rigor? Doing out the limits? 
2) I don't know how to show (rigorously) that they're NOT differentiable for $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will show that $f$ is not differentiable at the point $(x,y)$ whenever $x = 0$ or $y = 0$. WLOG, suppose that $x = 0$. If $f$ were differentiable at the point $(x,y)$, then $f^2$ would also be differentiable at that point. We have $f^2(x+h_1, y+h_2) - f^2(x,y) = |h_1|+|y+h_2|-|y|$. If $f^2$ were differentiable at $(x,y)$, there would exist $A \in M_{1 \times 2}$ such that $\frac{||h_1|+|y+h_2|-|y|-Ah|}{\| h\|} \to 0$ when $h \to 0$. With $h = t e_1$, we would find
$$
\frac{||t|+|y|-|y|-tA_1|}{|t|} = \left| 1-\frac{t}{|t|} A_1\right| \to 0 \,\ (t \to 0).
$$
But, this is impossible (consider $t \downarrow 0$ and $t \uparrow 0$).

Comment: I'm having trouble following your last step. Why is that impossible? It looks as if you have found such a map such that is differentiable.

Comment: On another note, what theorem allows for $f$ differentiable $\Rightarrow$ $f^2$ differentiable? I believe it and understand the logic, but I'm wondering if it's a named theorem

Comment: @Craig I've *supposed* that such an $A$ exist and have obtained a contradiction. $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t}{|t|}$ doesn't exist, so $\left| 1-\frac{t}{|t|} A_1 \right|$ can't tend to $0$ when $t \to 0$. As for the theorem, I don't know any name for it.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up figuring it out slightly differently, but I believe that your method is valid. I'll add my answer below for future reference

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: I'm just copying my answer from latex. You'll notice that I have a macro for \abs defined that obviously didn't transfer over. You can imagine though -- I'm just posting my answer for future reference

First, to show that $f$ is differentiable everywhere excluding $x=0$ or $y=0$, suppose $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$. For simplicity, define $a = \vert x\vert, x\neq 0$ and $b = \vert y \vert, y\neq 0$. Then $a,b$ are everywhere strictly positive and $f(a,b) = \sqrt{a + b}$. Taking partials, we find: 
$$Df(a,b) = \Big[ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{a+b}} \quad \frac{1}{2\sqrt{a+b}} \Big]$$
Both of which are everywhere continuous on our domain defined before. So $f$ is differentiable for $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$. Now we can explore those two 'trouble' cases.

WLOG, assume $y=0$. The proof would be the same if $x=0$, so I'll only do it one way. Define the sequences $a_n = (x, 1/n)$ and $b_n = (x, -1/n)$. Then, 
\begin{align*} 
 \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(a_n) -f(x,0)}{0 - 1/n} &= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{\vert x\vert + \vert 1/n\vert} - \sqrt{\vert x \vert}}{-1/n}\\
 &= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{2*\sqrt{\vert x\vert+\vert 1/n\vert}}*\frac{-1}{n^2}}{\frac{1}{n^2}} && \text{By L'Hospitals}\\ 
 & = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\vert x\vert + \vert1/n\vert}} \\ 
 & = -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\vert x\vert}} 
\end{align*}
However, if we approach from the other side (i.e. using $b_n$), we find: 
\begin{align*}
 \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(a_n) -f(x,0)}{0 + 1/n} &= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{\vert x\vert + \vert1/n\vert} - \sqrt{\vert x\vert}}{1/n}\\
 &= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{2*\sqrt{\vert x \vert+\vert 1/n\vert}}*\frac{-1}{n^2}}{-\frac{1}{n^2}} && \text{By L'Hospitals}\\ 
 & = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\vert x\vert + \vert 1/n\vert}} \\ 
 & = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\vert x\vert}} 
\end{align*}
And obviously those aren't equal, so $f$ is not differentiable on $(x,0)$ and, similarly, $(0,y)$.

Comment: Does this cover the case when $(x,y) = (0,0)$?