# Show that $\sqrt{|x| + |y|}$ is differentiable at nonzero points

Tags: limits, derivatives, partial-derivative

I know that there is a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/755263/show-where-fx-y-sqrtx-y-is-differentiable) showing that such a function $f(x,y) = \sqrt{|x|+|y|}$ is not differentiable at $x \neq 0$ or $y \neq 0$, but how do I show that $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at points such that both $x \neq 0$ and $y \neq 0$?

I can use the chain rule to take the partials, but how do I know that this derivative exists at a point that does not have zero in its coordinates? Specifically, the chain rule yields the first partial as $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{|x|+|y|}} $. Then how do I show that

$$\lim_{t\to0} \frac{1}{t}\left[f(x + te_j,y) - f(x,y) - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{|x|+|y|}} \right] = 0$$ when $x \neq 0$ and $y \neq 0$?

Comment: I am sure you mean $f(x,y) $ above, but otherwise, is not $f$ just a composition of differentiable functions if $x \neq 0$ and $y \neq 0$, and therefore continuous at these points? I thought the modulus would cause problems at either $x=0$ or $y=0$, but here  neither is  the case.

Comment: I meant differentiable, not continuous above, the rest of the comment still holds.

Comment: Can you show that $h(x,y) = \sqrt{x+y}$ is differentiable in the quadrant $x > 0$, $y > 0$?\

Comment: Exactly, @UmbertoP. The domain is disconnected, the components being open sets, so it suffices to look at each component, and the first quadrant will show the pattern.

Comment: It might be helpful to first understand a simpler situation: $|x|$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}.$

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I see what you mean. If I let $g(x, y) = |x| + |y|$ and $f(x) = \sqrt(x)$ and do a composition, would there be an issue since $g$ maps from $R^2$ to $R$ and $f$ maps from $R$ to $R$? I don't think so because the output of $g$ is in $R$. Just want to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set in the x,y plane of points with x$\neq$0 and y$\neq$0 is the union of 4 quadrants ;namely x>0 and y>0 ;x>0 and y<0 ;x<0 and y>0 ; x<0 and y<0 . In each quadrant the function z=g(x,y)= |x|+|y| is positive valued and continuously differentiable  . The function h(z)=$\sqrt{z}$ is continuously differentiable on the positive reals .  Thus the composition 
f(x,y)= h(g(x,y)) is continuosly differentiable .By continuously differentiable I mean that its partial derivatives are continuous . 
   It follows by a theorem of advanced calculus that f is differentiable  .In fact an induction argument can be used to show f is infinitely differentiable .